# eclipse: Gson installation: "Java Build Path"

Tags: java, eclipse, build, gson

I'm trying to install & work with Gson on Eclipse; I watch a toturial on youtube. One of the steps there, is to enter to: right click on the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path [in theleft menu] (screenshot from youtube here):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxErT.jpg)

The problem that I can't find the tab "Java Build Path" on Project -> Properties or anywhere else. My Eclipse screenshot here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2Azf.png)

Do you know where is this tab at?
Thanks.

Comment: Your _GsonProject_ is not a Java project (the project folder is not decorated with `J`) and has, therefore, no Java Build Path.

Comment: It's good to have a tutorial, but do not follow blindly without knowing what you do and what you want. So, Can you be more clear what do you want to do ? Add an external Library Jar ?

Comment: Yes, that's what i wanted to do. I found my problem (the next answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've understood that I had only a **folder** and NOT an Eclipse **project** and that's why I couldn't find this tab.